# Типовые решения

Tags: c++

Есть ли какие-нибудь типовые решения задач построения программных систем на С++? Какие есть, и где про них можно прочесть?

Comment: Есть......

Comment: @shurik, очень содержательно.

Comment: Какой вопрос - такой ответ. Автор вопроса хоть бы тематику упомянул.

Comment: @Expert, человек спросил, ему ответили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не [паттерны проектирования](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) имеете в виду?

Answer (score 0):

В С++ Builder есть возможность наследования когда-то один раз сделанной формы. Эту форму, содержащую контролы, потребные в семействе Ваших задач, можно дополнять своими элементами управления, в том числе и дополнительными меню, или делать невидимыми (недоступными) те, которые в данной задаче являются лишними.

Comment: Хай живе С++ Builder!

Comment: это немного не то

Comment: @mikillskegg. Категорически согласен.